# Opening an external url using a jquery dialog, but if nothing loads i want to display an error message inside it

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom, jquery-dialog

I am opening external url in jquery dialog using the below script. However some websites are not compatible in Frames and for those i want to display an error message. Please help me regarding that.
**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        var Button1 = $("#content_versionDetailsTabContainer_ctl00_ctl03_tdLicenseEvidenceUrl");
        var hiddenField = $("#content_versionDetailsTabContainer_ctl00_ctl03_captureURLHidden").val();
        var dialDiv = $("#content_dialog");
        var dialogObject = $("#dialogObject");
        if (hiddenField != "Nothing") {            
        $('#dialogObject').attr('data', hiddenField);                           
        Button1.mouseover(function (e) {                    
                dialDiv.css("visibility", "visible");
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#content_dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    position: ['left'],
                    show: 'blind',
                    hide: 'blind',
                    width: 640,
                    height: 600                    
                })
                if (dialogObject.find('head')) {
                    alert("found");
                    var testthis = dialogObject.find('html').html();
                    alert(testthis);
                }
                else { alert("not found") }
            });            
        }
    });
</script>
```

**aspx page:**

```
<div id="dialog" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden;overflow:auto;width:0px;height:0px;">
        <object type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" id="dialogObject"></object>
    </div>
```

Comment: also I am populating it using object inside <div>

Comment: Please provide us the error or its details!

Comment: @c0deslayer : i am not getting any error. in the error the whole html page gets populated. But i just have the Ids of object and external div. So how to check if the html page is loading or not?

Comment: also the url is not statis; it is dynamic depending upon user input.

Comment: @c0deslayer : I am trying to find the head element in dialog and then reading the html of <html> tag. However for all the urls i am getting alert of undefined. That's where I am stuck now

Comment: It won't be easy to validate external URLS due to limitation of CORS Headers by the external urls hosted servers. I won't say impossible. But at least not easy to do it using javascript. You might want to look for possible server-side approaches?

Comment: @c0deslayer : I actually want to find the html tag in the <object> and check if that <html> or <body> tags are getting populated. I am struggling to use find() method. I dont know if I am using correctly. Also I dont know how to check if those tags are getting populated.